# Regex matching sequence of characters

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have a test string such as: `The Sun and the Moon together, forever`

I want to be able to type a few characters or words and be able to match this string if the characters appear in the correct sequence together, even if there are missing words. For example, the following search word(s) should all match against this string:

`The Moon`
`Sun tog`
`Tsmoon`
`The get ever`

What regex pattern should I be using for this? I should add that the supplied test strings are going to be dynamic within an app, and so I'd like to be able to use a pattern based on the search string.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example `Tsmoon` you show partial words (`T`), ignoring case (`s`, `m`) and allow anything between each entered character. So as a first attempt you can:

1. Set the ignore case option
2. Between each chapter input insert the regular expression to match zero or more of anything. You can choose whether to match the shortest or longest run.

Try that, reading the documentation for `NSRegularExpression` if you're stuck, and see how it goes. If you get stuck ask a new question showing your code and the RE constructed and explain what happens/doesn't work as expected.

HTH

Comment: Ended up with: "(?i).*t.*s.*m" and so on